# Lining 4 images across the page

Tags: css

The first 4 images are the same size and I need to line them up across the page evenly.  How can I do this with HML5 and CSS please?

```
<block>
    <img id="bedroom" src="photos/bedroom1.jpg" alt="bedroom furniture">
    <img id="dining" src="photos/dining.jpg" alt="dining furniture" >
    <img id="lounge" src="photos/lounge.jpg" alt="lounge furniture">
    <img id="office" src="photos/office.jpg" alt="office furniture">
</block>
    <img id="lounge2" src="photos/lounge2.jpg" alt="large loungeroom funiture">
    <img id="mixed" src="photos/mixed.jpg" alt="A mix of furniture">
```

CSS:

```
#logo  {position: relative; margin-left:650px; }
nav {background-color: red; border-color: black; border-style:ridge; 
    position: relative; max-width: 100%; text-align: center; padding: 10px;}
nav li {display: inline; }  
nav a {color:black; padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;} 
nav a:visited {color:blue;}
nav a:hover {color: green;}
block { position:absolute; padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px; width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Try this: http://radiatingstar.com/distribute-divs-images-equaly-line

Answer (score 0):

```
#genericClass {
  float:left;
}
```

Should line them all up I believe.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow! Now first off, your code was a bit confusing, and did not make too much sense. Such as parts of your css where irrelevant to your HTML code, (`nav` was not seen in your HTML).

To answer your question though, what you are looking for is the CSS tag `float`.

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.
>   ***https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float***

When using `float` you can use `left` or `right`, *and of course: none, inital, inherit*. The one that you need specifically is `float: left`, and that will tell all elements to align to the left of the page next to each other.

I have written up a nice little **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9ankk414/1/)** for you :)

If you have any more questions on how float works you can either Google it (or Bing it...), or just post it as a question comment :)